# Add rectangular patch on heatmap's cell using Plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, visualization, heatmap

I am visualizing a heatmap using Plotly, and I want to add rectangular patches/borders around some specific cells on that heatmap.

I just wonder if there is any way to do that. I see that they have similar function in matplotlib that allows users to add rectangular borders on heatmap cells `add_patch(Rectangle((i,j), 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='gray', lw=3))`. But I have not found similar function provided by plotly.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution for it. You can simply add scatters for your heatmap visualization by adding the code below.

```
    fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(mode="markers", x=x_patch, y=y_patch, marker_symbol=[101],
                   marker_color="darkgray", 
                   marker_line_width=2, marker_size=22, hovertemplate= 'x: %{x}<br>y: %{y}<br>z: %{z}<extra></extra>'))
```

In order to custom your marker, you can take a look at this example [here](https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/#custom-marker-symbols). In this case, I want to add square-open marker and the code for this marker is 101. Hope that it will help someone :)